# Responsive row of images and text

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I've lined up five images on a row with text below each one and I'm trying to make it responsive. The problem is that all the images don't scale down properly. I want them all to have the same width & height.

---

My code so far:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/thumb160_268/1210514734LWUcju.jpg" />
            <p>testing text</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/thumb160_268/1210514734LWUcju.jpg" />
            <p>Longerishhh texting text</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/thumb160_268/1210514734LWUcju.jpg" />
            <p>Text</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/thumb160_268/1210514734LWUcju.jpg" />
            <p>Quite long text</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/thumb160_268/1210514734LWUcju.jpg" />
            <p>More testing</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    width: 100%;
}

table{
    width: 80%;
}

td{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

img{
    width: 100%;    
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7CrV/)

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Y7CrV/4/  OR http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the following to the table css:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

In your case:

```
table {
    width: 80%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

updated jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/Y7CrV/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
html{
    width: 100%;
}

table{
    width: 80%;
}
tr{width:100%;}
td{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: baseline;
word-break: break-all;
}

img{
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use floating divs?

```
div.row {
    width: 80%;
}

/* clearfix */
div.row { zoom:1; }
div.row:before, div.row:after { content:""; display:table; }
div.row:after { clear:both; }

div.row .column {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7CrV/8/

But if you want more flexibility, you may want to have a look at http://foundation.zurb.com/grid.php